# Removing a tuple from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I need help removing an tuple from an array. I have tried .delete, .remove and .pop to no prevail. Please help!

> remove(red, green, blue): Removes the given RGB color from the colormap. The color must be contained in the colormap in order to be removed.

```
from ezarrays import Array

class Colormap :
  def __init__ (self, k) :
    self._theColors = Array(k)
    self._capacity = k
    self._numItems = 0

  def __len__(self) :
    return self._numItems

  def contains(self, red, green, blue) :
    color = Color(red, green, blue)
    for i in range(self._numItems) :
        if self._theColors[i].red == red :
            if self._theColors[i].green == green :
                if self._theColors[i].blue == blue :
                    return True
        return False  

  def add(self, red, green, blue) :
    if self._numItems == self._capacity :
        self._expandArray()
    color = Color(red, green, blue)
    index = self._numItems
    self._theColors[index] = color
    self._numItems = self._numItems + 1  

  def remove(self, red, green, blue) :
    color = Color(red, green, blue)
    for i in range(len(self)) :
        if self._theColors[i].red == red :
            if self._theColors[i].green == green :
                if self._theColors[i].blue == blue :
                    self._theColors.remove(red)
                    self._theColors.delete(color.green)
                    self._theColors.delete(color.blue)
                    self._numItems = self._numItems - 1
        else :
            return -1

  def map(self, red, green, blue) :
    pass

  def itBegin(self) :
    pass

  def itNext(self) :
    pass

  # Helper method to extend the length of the array.
  def _expandArray(self) :
    tempArray = Array( self._numItems * 2 )
    self._capacity = self._capacity * 2
    for i in range(len(self._theColors)) :
        tempArray[i] = self._theColors[i]
    self._theColors = tempArray


# Storage class holding the color values.    
class Color :
  def __init__ (self, red, green, blue) :
    if red < 0 :
        red = 0
    elif red > 255 :
        red = 255
    self.red = red

    if green < 0 :
        green = 0
    elif green > 255 :
        green = 255
    self.green = green

    if blue < 0 :
        blue = 0
    elif blue > 255 :
        blue = 255
    self.blue = blue
```

This is the arrays module we are given to use the python array.

EZARRAYS

```
import ctypes  

class Array :
   # Creates an array with size elements.
  def __init__( self, size ):               
    assert size > 0, "Array size must be > 0"
    self._size = size    

     # Create the array structure using the ctypes module.
    PyArrayType = ctypes.py_object * size          
    self._elements = PyArrayType()

     # Initialize each element.
    self.clear(None)                        

   # Returns the size of the array.
  def __len__( self ):
    return self._size

   # Gets the contents of the index element.
  def __getitem__( self, index ):                  
    assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
    return self._elements[ index ]

   # Puts the value in the array element at index position.
  def __setitem__( self, index, value ):
    assert index >= 0 and index < len(self), "Array subscript out of range"
    self._elements[ index ] = value                 

   # Clears the array by setting each element to the given value.
  def clear( self, value ) :
    for i in range(len(self)) :
      self._elements[i] = value


# Implementation of the Array2D ADT using an array of arrays. 
class Array2D :  
   # Creates a 2-D array of size numRows x numCols.
  def __init__( self, numRows, numCols ):
     # Create a 1-D array to store an array reference for each row.
    self._theRows = Array(numRows)

     # Create the 1-D arrays for each row of the 2-D array.
    for i in range( numRows ) :
      self._theRows[i] = Array(numCols)

   # Returns the number of rows in the 2-d array.
  def numRows( self ):
    return len( self._theRows )

   # Returns the number of columns in the 2-d array.
  def numCols( self ):
    return len( self._theRows[0] )

   # Clears the array by setting every element to the given value.
  def clear( self, value ):
    for row in range(len(self._theRows)) :
      self._theRows[row].clear(value)

   # Get the contents of the element at position [i, j]
  def __getitem__( self, ndxTuple ):                                
    assert len(ndxTuple) == 2, "Invalid number of array subscripts." 
    row = ndxTuple[0]
    col = ndxTuple[1]
    assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
       and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
           "Array subscript out of range."
    the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
    return the1dArray[col]                       

   # Set the contents of the element at position [i,j] to value.
  def __setitem__( self, ndxTuple, value ):
    assert len(ndxTuple) == 2, "Invalid number of array subscripts."    
    row = ndxTuple[0]
    col = ndxTuple[1]
    assert row >= 0 and row < self.numRows() \
       and col >= 0 and col < self.numCols(), \
           "Array subscript out of range."
    the1dArray = self._theRows[row]
    the1dArray[col] = value
```

Comment: Do we need to see _all_ this code, uncluding the f-word? Please produce an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Might wanna take the "blue" language out of your code there...

Comment: What is the "ezarrays" module? That's not in PyPi.

Comment: What is it with programmers and using swear words when debugging with prints :D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, missed one...

Comment: Lmao, didn't see that, thanks.

Comment: The bad language was left over from a friend who was trying to help me get the remove method working

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in `Colormap.remove()`. It seems you are attempting to remove the fields within the `Color` object, which is stored as an element in the Array, when I think you are trying to remove the element from the Array. A solution would be to create a new Array and populating it with the desired element (all but the one you are trying to remove).

```
  def remove(self, red, green, blue) :
    color = Color(red, green, blue)
    for i in range(len(self)) :
        if self._theColors[i].red == red :
            if self._theColors[i].green == green :
                if self._theColors[i].blue == blue :
                    # Changes made below this line
                    self._numItems = self._numItems - 1
                    tempArray = Array( self._capacity )
                    ind = 0
                    for j in range(len(self)) :
                        if j is not i:
                            tempArray[ind] = self._theColors[ind]
                            ind = ind + 1
                    self._theColors = tempArray
        else :
            return -1
```

After that, it seems like this works alright, except for Colormap.contains() returning None instead of False.

```
cmap = Colormap(1)
cmap.add(100,100,100)
print(cmap.contains(100,100,100))  # Prints "True"
cmap.remove(100,100,100)  
print(cmap.contains(100,100,100))  # Prints "None"
```

I'm not too familiar with the ctypes library, but if you can find a way to remove the element `self._theColors[i]`, this would have the same effect.